# Matplotlib: Why would a KNN regression model draw a line through ALL points regardless of K?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

Having difficulty doing something very basic: create a random dataset taking on values between -1,1, plot them, and also fit a KNN model to the data and fit it over the data. Using numpy to create the dataset.

The KNN fitted line looks like a spider web. Unsure where I went wrong in the code.
K=2 in the image, but the problem is identical even if I set K = 80.
[image]
https://github.com/PortWhisperer/MachineLearningStudies/blob/master/crappy-KNN.py

Answer (score 0):

I sorted the X array with numpy.sort() and the plot sorted itself out.

[image]